# How to set default NULL values for all class maps in CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

**Is is possible to set default NullValues in CsvReader configuration?**

Currently I have class map for each record model and I set `TypeConverterOprions.NullValues("NULL")` for each column.

```
public class MyRecord 
{
   string Prop1 {get; set;}
   string Prop2 {get; set;}
}
public class MyRecordMap : ClassMap 
{
   public MyRecordMap() 
   {
       base.AutoMap();
       Map(m => m.Prop1).TypeConverterOption.NullValues("NULL");
       Map(m => m.Prop2).TypeConverterOption.NullValues("NULL");
   }
}
```

Comment: The settings are from oledb connection.  The oledb settings are the same as excel or access db where the types are determined automatically if the columns are not defined.

Comment: @jdweng: I have no idea what are you talking about. What settings? What oledb?

Comment: CSVReader is using a oledb connection.  As far as I know there is no way of setting defaults on oledb.